# Change language and its url in django

Tags: django, internationalization

I have a two language site in Django, and a Select form to change the language of the site. It was working fine, until I started using `i18n_patterns` in urls. So now, every url of my site starts with: `foo.com/en/` or `foo.com/es/`.

The problem is that when I change the language using the form, the url setting overrides the selection of the form, so the language is not beeing changed. The only way to achieve that, is doing it manually from the url.

But, I don't want to link all the language changes to the initial page. The url could be something like `foo.com/en/post/foo-post/` and I would like to be able to change it to `foo.com/es/post/foo-post/`. What am I doing wrong?

My form is:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <select name="language"  onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="es" {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == "es" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Español</option>
        <option value="eu"  {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == "en" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>English</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a webpage with multilanguage selection, here is an example from my base.html template. I hope you find it useful.

```html
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_PREFIX %}
<head>
...
<script>    
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $('#language').change(function() {
        window.location.replace("/" + $('#language').val() + "/index");
    });
});
</script>
...
</head>

<body>
....
<select id="language" name="language">
    {% if CURRENT_LANGUAGE == 'es' %}
        <option value="es" selected="yes">{% trans "Espaniol" %}</option>
    {% else %}
        <option value="es">{% trans "Espaniol" %}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% if CURRENT_LANGUAGE == 'en' %}
        <option value="en" selected="yes">{% trans "Ingles" %}</option>
    {% else %}
        <option value="en">{% trans "Ingles" %}</option>
    {% endif %}
</select>
...
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand your approach. If I'm in `foo.com/es/` and I change it to english, it is redirecting me to `foo.com/en/index`. In my case, a pretty `Page not found` error message ;). Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Is an example. Edit the url.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean.